# Verizon Fivespot firewall

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, remote-access

I have a Verizon Fivespot Wi-Fi router and am having issues connecting to the computer that uses it to get on the internet. I am able to connect to the Fivespot admin pages remotely and I am able to connect to the internet from the computer behind the Fivespot.

There are two sections pertinent to this issue, Port Filtering
[image]
And, Port Forwarding
[image]
I've tried each individually and both together but cannot access anything through the router except for the admin page.

I am trying to connect through SSH to an Ubuntu 10.04 box over Wi-Fi.

I have called Verizon Tech Support but they were unhelpful, the person essentially read what it says on each screen without any elaboration.

Edit - I've discovered that the port filtering is for outgoing traffic, I have disabled any filtering on the outgoing traffic. So I think I'm halfway there.

Comment: Did you put in the right IP address and port range?

Comment: @digitxp yes, I'm putting in the local IP address of the computer (192.168.0.252)

Comment: Is this a static IP?

Comment: The Verizon Fivespot is not a static IP but I know the current IP is correct.  I have not setup the computer as a static IP since I'm still just working on getting access to the computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out a solution but unfortunately, not the cause.

I have setup the Port Forwarding so that *:8080 points to port 80 on the server.

This worked, while setting up *:22 to port 20 on the server did not.

I have since discovered that port forwarding any port to the same port on the server does NOT work, but forwarding any port to any *different* port number will work (assuming the port number is not reserved)

[image: Verizon Fivespot Port Forwarding]